# Using newcommand and newenvironment to print a labled tabular

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, environments

I posted this question as guest with some issues that should be fixed in this version so here it goes.

I have the following self defined counter and command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{usecase}[section]
\newcommand{\usecasenumber}{\arabic{usecase} \stepcounter{usecase}
\newcommand{\usecase}[9]{
    \begin{tabular}{| p{4cm} | p{8cm} |}
        \hline
        Anwendungsfall-Nummer       & U-\usecasenumber  \\
        \hline
        Hauptakteur                 & #1                \\
        \hline
        Andere Akteure              & #2                \\
        \hline
        Beschreibung                & #3                \\
        \hline
        Vorbedingung                & #4                \\
        \hline
        Nachbedingung               & #5                \\
        \hline
        Ausführung                  & #6                \\
        \hline
        Alternativen                & #7                \\
        \hline
        Ausnahmen                   & #8                \\
        \hline
        Benutzte Anwendungsfälle    & #9                \\      
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
\usecase{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}
\end{document}
```

I now want an environment named `usecase` that does the exact same thing my newcommand does plus adding another line to the table with the name that one should be able to give the usecase environment. The environment should be able to automatically increase the counter and I want to be able to add labels to the usecase environment (just like it is possible in figure or table). When I reference such a label with `\ref` I want the reference to be the number of the environment given by the counter usecase.

I am not sure how to realize that or if it is even possible. I would start with something like this but I don't know how to proceed from there on to achieve the desired behaviour.

```
\newenvironment{usecase}[1]{\refstepcounter{usecase}}{
    % TODO
}
```

It would be really appreciated if someone could help me out here. :)

## Edit:

Alternatively, I woul be O.K. with a floating environment named usecase that takes a paramater that will be its caption. If that makes it any easier.

Comment: It's hard to understand what the environment's content should look like.

Comment: The content should look exactly like the ouput my minimal example produces but with an extra line at the beginning of the tabular where the first line looks like `Anwendungsfall & <<parameter of the usecase environment>>`

Comment: I meant the *input* between `\begin{usecase}` and `\end{usecase}`.

Comment: The MWE does not compile, at least with my installation of texlive, `File ended while scanning use of \@argdef`

Comment: This is the some the question like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302985/using-newcommand-inside-newenvironment-to-print-a-table