# Creating reusable table with one column's data different each time

Tags: tables

I am attempting to write a design document that lists a number of requirements.  Each section of the document then describes an entity that needs to fulfil those requirements, and I have decided the best way to document this is a table that shows up in each section, with the same column headers and same data in the first column of the table (`\autoref`'s pointing to the requirements), while each section will fill in the second column with custom descriptions of how that entity fulfils each requirement.

I considered writing a macro that did all of this, but I would need around two dozen parameters into it (one for each row of the table).  Additionally, when I add a new row to the template I would like a default value (specifically a `\todo{}`) to be autofilled in the second column of that row for every later instance of the table.  I am also okay putting the template in the preamble, since I think that will be required.

I know I could do this with a monster of a macro, but I would prefer to avoid working around the parameter limit (and handling defaults would be more difficult) so I am hoping someone knows a more elegant way to get the repeated structure I want.

Comment: You either need a keyvalue interface or refer to external macro 'variables'

Comment: you should be able to create a macro with arguments that defines just one row of a table, as well as a (fixed) macro that defines the table header. that would leave you with the task of filling in the rows, including the row header.  if you made a small "template" with row headers already filled in for all the rows you need, that you can cut-and-paste using your editor, that would leave you with just a fairly simple outline that you can fill in with the variable information as needed.

Comment: Perhaps something like in my answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302985/using-newcommand-inside-newenvironment-to-print-a-table???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Christian Hupfer's comment I got a working solution going.

```
% Set up the requirement table macro
\usepackage{xkeyval}
% Required for \define@key to work
\makeatletter
% Define the default value that is assigned to the key
\def\contentRowOne{\todo[inline]{Fill in cell}}
% Define the key for parsing
\define@key{brt}{keyRowOne}{%
    \def\contentRowOne{#1}%
}
% Here you would add more \def and \define@key commands for each key needed
% Revert the changes made by \makeatletter
\makeatother

% This is the macro that is used in the body of the document
\newcommand\busreqtab[1][]{
% Grouping makes sure that later calls get the default values rather than
% the values from the last table
\begingroup 
% This parses the optional key-value parameters and runs the defined macros
% for each
\setkeys{brt}{#1}
% Standard table with the macros used here
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|p{5cm}|}
    \hline
    Requirement & Fulfilled by \\
    \hline
    \autoref{req:label} & \contentRowOne \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
% end of the group, replaces the changes to the key macros with default values
\endgroup
}

\begin{document}
% Generates table with todo in second column
\busreqtab
% Generates table with Test in second column
\busreqtab[contentRowOne=Test]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example similar to Christian Hupfer's answer but using `pgfkeys` instead of `xkeyval`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys, pgffor} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

% this command is used for undefined cells
\newcommand{\undefinedcell}{\textcolor{red}{undefined}}

% set up the keys that store the entries
\pgfkeys{table/.is family, table, 
    list of rows/.initial={foo, bar, baz},
    add row/.style={#1/.value required, #1/.initial={\undefinedcell}},
    /table, first column/.is family, first column,
    /table/add row/.list/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/table/list of rows},
    /table, second column/.is family, second column,
    /table/add row/.list/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/table/list of rows},
}

% code to store the content of the table in a key
    \pgfkeys{table,
    content/.initial={},
    add content/.style = {
        content/.append={#1 & \pgfkeysvalueof{/table/first column/#1} & \pgfkeysvalueof{/table/second column/#1} \\\hline},
    }, 
    fill content/.style = {add content/.list/.expanded = \pgfkeysvalueof{/table/list of rows}},
}

% define the entries in the first column
\pgfkeys{table, first column,
    foo = entry 1,
    bar = entry 2   
}

% the command takes a list of key=val pairs and adds them to the second column
\newcommand{\printtable}[1]{
    \begingroup
    \pgfkeys{table, second column, #1, /table, fill content}
        \begin{tabular}{|l | l | l |}\hline
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/table/content}
        \end{tabular}
    \endgroup
}

\parindent=0pt 
\begin{document}

\section{First}
\printtable{foo=1}  

\section{Second}
\printtable{bar=2}

\end{document}
```

[image: The generated table]

Comment: I just got mine working following his example using the xkeyval package, which I will be posting shortly, but having it done with multiple packages is always a plus.